# regular expression (perl like)

Tags: regex, string, perl

> $str1="ssh_2-4^accept IN=ETH2 OUT=eth33
>   MAC=00:d0:c9:96:62:c0:00:1c:f0:98:19:57:08:00 SRC=192.168.200.30
>   DST=192.168.200.224 LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=30546 DF
>   PROTO=TCP SPT=10159 DPT=4319 WINDOW=7300 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0";
>
> $str2="ssh_2-4^accept IN=ETH2 OUT=eth33
>   MAC=00:d0:c9:96:62:c0:00:1c:f0:98:19:57:08:00 SRC=192.168.200.30
>   DST=192.168.200.224 LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=30546 DF
>   PROTO=ICMP WINDOW=7300 RES=0x00 URGP=0";

I need to capture:

for $str1 ==> ssh_2-4, accept, ETH@, eth33, 192.168.200.30, 192.168.200.224, TCP, 10159, 4319

for $str2 ==> ssh_2-4, accept, ETH@, eth33, 192.168.200.30, 192.168.200.224, ICMP

I use below regexp and work very well for the $str1, but don't work with $str2:

```
(\w*)\^(\w*).*IN=(\S*).*OUT=(\S*).*SRC=(\S* ).*DST=(\S*).*PROTO=(\S*).*SPT=(\d*).*DPT=(\d*).*
```

What is the suitable regexp for this purpose?

Comment: It does not match for `$str2` because the `SPT` and `DPT` field is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$str1="ssh_2-4^accept IN=ETH2 OUT=eth33 MAC=00:d0:c9:96:62:c0:00:1c:f0:98:19:57:08:00 SRC=192.168.200.30 DST=192.168.200.224 LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=30546 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=10159 DPT=4319 WINDOW=7300 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0";
$str2="ssh_2-4^accept IN=ETH2 OUT=eth33 MAC=00:d0:c9:96:62:c0:00:1c:f0:98:19:57:08:00 SRC=192.168.200.30 DST=192.168.200.224 LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=30546 DF PROTO=ICMP WINDOW=7300 RES=0x00 URGP=0";

foreach my $i ($str1, $str2) {
    if ($i =~ /^(.+)\^(\w+)\s+IN=(\S+)\s+OUT=(\S+).*?SRC=(\S+)\s+DST=(\S+).*?PROTO=(\S+)(?:.*?SPT=(\d+)\s+DPT=(\d+))?/) {
        print "/1=$1/2=$2/3=$3/4=$4/5=$5/6=$6/7=$7/8=$8/9=$9\n";
    }
}
```

This gives

```
/1=ssh_2-4/2=accept/3=ETH2/4=eth33/5=192.168.200.30/6=192.168.200.224/7=TCP/8=10159/9=4319
/1=ssh_2-4/2=accept/3=ETH2/4=eth33/5=192.168.200.30/6=192.168.200.224/7=ICMP/8=/9=
```

Capture the SPT and DPT parts in an optional sub-bracket: `(?:.*?SPT=(\d+)\s+DPT=(\d+))?`

Answer (score 2):

A split would seem more robust and clean to me. For example:

```
$str2=~  /^(.*?)\^(\w*)\s+(.*)$/;
my($version,$action,$args) = ($1,$2,$3);
my %argsmap =  split(/[= ]/, $args);
print "proto=$argsmap{'PROTO'} \n";
```

Edited: I wrongly assumed that each "field" had a `key=value` pair. Fixed version:

```
  my(@args) = split(/ /,$str2);
  my($version,$action) = split(/\^/,shift @args);
  my %argsmap = map { $_ =~ /(.*)=(.*)/ ? ($1,$2) : ($_,'') } @args;
```

Comment: I get an "Odd number of elements" error when I try this. I think you need to compensate for that.

Answer (score 0):

The greedy quantifiers means that each time the expression makes a match, it matches `.*` to all the rest of the characters in the line. Which means that *each* time it matches it has to consume the input, fail to find the next expression, and then backtrack until it does. This is *highly* inefficient.

Instead you want to use the non-greedy form: `.*?`. And then to make sure you get whole words/keys, you could use the word-break specifier: `\b`, like so:

```
my $re 
    = qr/
        ([\w-]*) \^ (\w*) .*? 
        \bIN=(\S*)  .*?
        \bOUT=(\S*) .*?
        \bSRC=(\S*) .*?
        \bDST=(\S*) .*?
        \bPROTO=(\S*)
        (?: .*? 
            \bSPT=(\d*) 
            .*?
            \bDPT=(\d*)
        )?
    /x;
```

Now, since you don't have SPT and DPT fields in each line, you want to make that match conditional `(?:...)?`

And that's all I needed to do:

```
while ( <$data> ) {
    my @flds = m/$re/;
    print join( ',', grep { defined and length } @flds ), "\n"; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A more fleshed out split version, based on [leonbloy's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/277304/leonbloy) answer. A direct split will not work due to odd number of elements. So instead we split explicitly on `=` and allow empty values to be undefined to preserve the hash key/value pairs.

**Code:**

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str1="ssh_2-4^accept IN=ETH2 OUT=eth33 MAC=00:d0:c9:96:62:c0:00:1c:f0:98:19:57:08:00 SRC=192.168.200.30 DST=192.168.200.224 LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=30546 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=10159 DPT=4319 WINDOW=7300 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0";
my $str2="ssh_2-4^accept IN=ETH2 OUT=eth33 MAC=00:d0:c9:96:62:c0:00:1c:f0:98:19:57:08:00 SRC=192.168.200.30 DST=192.168.200.224 LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=30546 DF PROTO=ICMP WINDOW=7300 RES=0x00 URGP=0";

my @data;
for my $str ($str1, $str2) {
    my %hash;
    # First we extract the "header"
    $str =~ s/^([^^]+)\^(\w+) // || die "Did not match header";
    $hash{'version'} = $1;
    $hash{'action'} = $2;

    # Now process the args
    for my $line (split ' ', $str) {
        my ($key, $val) = split /=/, $line;
        $hash{$key} = $val;
    }
    # Save the hash into an array
    push @data, \%hash;
}

for my $href (@data) {
    # Now output the selected elements from each hash
    my $out = join ", ",
        @$href{'version','action','IN','OUT','SRC','DST','PROTO'};
    if ($href->{'PROTO'} eq 'TCP') {
        $out = join ", ", $out, @$href{'SPT', 'DPT'};
    }
    print "$out\n";
}
```

**Output:**

```
ssh_2-4, accept, ETH2, eth33, 192.168.200.30, 192.168.200.224, TCP, 10159, 4319
ssh_2-4, accept, ETH2, eth33, 192.168.200.30, 192.168.200.224, ICMP
```